# Using form selectors outside a form element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have several forms loaded via AJAX so to avoid nested forms I want to use some *select* and *checkbox* selectors here and there to trigger some jquery actions but not inside a *form* element. Something like:

```
<div>
[select]    [checkbox]
    [form via ajax][/form]
[select]    [checkbox]
    [form via ajax][/form]
[select]    [checkbox]
</div>
```

Seems work well in firefox and chrome but is it really a legal practice? THX.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, it's completely fine to have form controls outside of a `<form>` tag. The [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.1) states this:

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM
>   element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration
>   when they are used to build user interfaces.

However, form controls outside of a `form` tag are not what the spec calls "successful controls", which means they cannot be submitted along with a form (fairly obviously).

The section of the spec on [intrinsic events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#events) goes on to state the following:

> Control elements such as INPUT, SELECT, BUTTON, TEXTAREA, and LABEL
>   all respond to certain intrinsic events. When these elements do not
>   appear within a form, they may be used to augment the graphical user
>   interface of the document.
>
> For instance, authors may want to include press buttons in their
>   documents that do not submit a form but still communicate with a
>   server when they are activated.

That seems to be pretty much exactly the sort of thing you're doing, so yes, it's completely valid to do it.

Comment: Very clear, thanks! but I refer to trigger _jquery_ actions (yes, I just added _jquery_ in the question's body, I thought it was clear just putting in the tags section) I imagine that being a valid HTML practice will work fine with jquery, Thanks again...

Comment: Of course, jQuery can select any element in the DOM. Form controls are valid outside of `form` tags, so jQuery will have no problem selecting them.